# C# Comparing List objects to passed parameters

Tags: c#, list, c#-4.0

What I am trying to do is get the number of right angled triangles between 1 and 20 on both sides.

Most of the logic is fine, but when I want to check for 3, 4 and 5 this is one triangle, while  4, 3 and 5 would not be valid as it 3, 4, 5 in a different order.

Here is the code that I have written for the problem area

```
public bool isAlreadyValidTriangle(int intAdj, int intOpp, List<Triangle> triangleList)
{
    bool breakLoop = false;
    Int32 length = triangleList.Count;
    for (int index = 0; index < length && breakLoop != false; index++)
    {
        //This is to compare an existing adjacent that is stored in the list to the
        //supplied opposite, this is to prebent the 3, 4, 5 and 4, 3, 5 issue
        var response = triangleList.Find(r => r.IntAdjacent == intOpp);

        if (response !=null)
        {
            //This is to compare an existing opposite that is stored in the list to the
            //supplied adjacent, this is to prebent the 3, 4, 5 and 4, 3, 5 issue
            var otherResponse = triangleList.Find(r => r.IntOpposite == intAdj);

            if (otherResponse != null)
            {
                breakLoop = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return breakLoop;
}
```

Just in case anybody needs the Triangle code, here it is

```
public class Triangle
{
    private int intAdjacent;
    private int intOpposite;
    private int intHypotenuse;

    public Triangle(int intAdjacent, int intOpposite, int intHypotenuse)
    {
        this.intAdjacent = intAdjacent;
        this.intOpposite = intOpposite;
        this.intHypotenuse = intHypotenuse;
    }

    public int IntAdjacent
    {
        get { return intAdjacent; }
    }

    public int IntOpposite
    {
        get { return intOpposite; }
    }

    public int IntHypotenuse
    {
        get { return intHypotenuse; }
    }
}
```

Could some one spot to see where I am making a mistake in the logic or have made an error in the code itself?
Keith

Comment: "What I am trying to do is get the number of right angled triangles between 1 and 20 on both sides." Read this back to yourself, and consider that a triangle has three sides. These can't all be addressed by the term "both". Are you looking for triangles with all sides shorter than 20? Wouldn't the list be infinite?

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly your goal is, what results you are expecting and what the actual problem is?

Comment: The code won't work precisely since your approach is a little wrong. Saying this, because you are searching the whole list which may contain many objects with loads of values, so the Find method returns a value anywhere it finds it rather than in a specific index. You have to compare the value for each specific index of the list instead.

Comment: What is the relationship of `intAdj` & `intOpp` to triangleList? Also what is the purpose of the `for` loop? I dont see `index` being used inside the loop.

Comment: @spender When he says "both", it's accurate as they are right-angled triangles, so the hypotenuse won't change, it's only the adjacent and opposite that switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this quite a lot like this:

```
public bool isAlreadyValidTriangle(int intAdj, int intOpp, List<Triangle> triangleList)
{
    if(triangleList.Any(t => t.IntAdjacent == intAdj && t.IntOpposite == intOpp))
        return true;

    return triangleList.Any(t => t.IntAdjacent == intOpp && t.IntOpposite == intAdj);

}
```

It first looks for any matches where the passed in values are a match, then reverses the search if they don't. It's slightly different to your code in that it looks for both adjacent and opposite at the same time which is where you went wrong. Additionally, it uses `Any` which returns a boolean value if any item is found that matches.

Thinking about this further, I would change the function to make it an extension method like this:

```
public static bool isAlreadyValidTriangle(this List<Triangle> triangleList, int intAdj, int intOpp)
{
    if(triangleList.Any(t => t.IntAdjacent == intAdj && t.IntOpposite == intOpp))
        return true;

    return triangleList.Any(t => t.IntAdjacent == intOpp && t.IntOpposite == intAdj);

}
```

This means you can call it with a little more readability:

```
List<Triangle> triangleList = new List<Triangle>();
... fill list with triangles ...

if(triangleList.isAlreadyValidTriangle(adjacent, opposite)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Transcendent I don't understand what you are saying. My code is different as it's comparing both adjacent and opposite at the same time.

Comment: Sorry misunderstood your code, that's right, I didn't notice the `&&`

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks for the advice and help.

Here is the complete code from start to finish

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Collections;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
    public class Program
    {
    private static double doubleHypotenuse = 0;
    private static int adjacent = 1;
    private static int opposite = 1;
    private static int limit = 200;
    private static int count = 0;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        TriangleLogic triLogic = new TriangleLogic();
        List<Triangle> triangleList = new List<Triangle>();
        List<Triangle> trianglePlus1 = new List<Triangle>();

        while (adjacent < limit)
        {
            opposite = 1;
            while (opposite < limit)
            {
                doubleHypotenuse = triLogic.intRightAngle(adjacent, opposite);
                if (doubleHypotenuse % 1 == 0)
                {
                    if (!triLogic.isAlreadyValidTriangle(adjacent, opposite, triangleList))
                    {
                        triangleList.Add(new Triangle(adjacent, opposite, (int)Convert.ToInt32(doubleHypotenuse)));
                    }

                    count++;
                }
                opposite++;
            }
            adjacent++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The following are integer triangles");
        triangleList.ForEach(delegate(Triangle pytag)
        {
            if ((pytag.IntHypotenuse - pytag.IntOpposite) == 1)
            {
                trianglePlus1.Add(new Triangle(pytag.IntAdjacent, pytag.IntOpposite, pytag.IntHypotenuse));
            }
            Console.WriteLine(pytag.IntAdjacent + ", " + pytag.IntOpposite + " and " + pytag.IntHypotenuse);
        });

        Console.WriteLine("the number of squares is " + count);
        Int32 length = triangleList.Count;
        Console.WriteLine("the length of the list is " + length);

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("the List of triangles with the hypotenuse 1 ");
        Console.WriteLine("more than the opposite");

        trianglePlus1.ForEach(delegate(Triangle pytagPlus1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pytagPlus1.IntAdjacent + ", " + pytagPlus1.IntOpposite + " and " + pytagPlus1.IntHypotenuse);
        });


        Int32 lengthPlus1 = trianglePlus1.Count;
        Console.WriteLine("the length of the list is " + lengthPlus1);

    }
}
}
```

Here is the Triangle Class

```
    public class Triangle
    {
    private int intAdjacent;
    private int intOpposite;
    private int intHypotenuse;

    public Triangle(int intAdjacent, int intOpposite, int intHypotenuse)
    {
        this.intAdjacent = intAdjacent;
        this.intOpposite = intOpposite;
        this.intHypotenuse = intHypotenuse;
    }

    public int IntAdjacent
    {
        get { return intAdjacent; }
    }

    public int IntOpposite
    {
        get { return intOpposite; }
    }

    public int IntHypotenuse
    {
        get { return intHypotenuse; }
    }
}
```

And finally the TriangleLogic class

```
    public class TriangleLogic
    {
    private double squareAdjacent = 0;
    private double squareOpposite = 0;
    private double squareSum = 0;

    public TriangleLogic()
    {

    }

    public double intRightAngle(int intAdjacent, int intOpposite)
    {
        squareAdjacent = Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(intAdjacent), 2);
        squareOpposite = Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(intOpposite), 2);
        squareSum = squareAdjacent + squareOpposite;
        return Math.Sqrt(squareSum);
    }

    public bool isAlreadyValidTriangle(int intAdj, int intOpp, List<Triangle> triangleList)
    {
        if (triangleList.Any(t => t.IntAdjacent == intAdj && t.IntOpposite == intOpp))
            return true;

        return triangleList.Any(t => t.IntAdjacent == intOpp && t.IntOpposite == intAdj);
    }
}
```

Thanks again for the support

Comment: I made another edit to my answer. I know you already accepted but it's been bugging me and I had to make the change :)